# DataGridViewCheckBox cell check event in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have `DataGridViewCheckBox` column that is unbound. When user changes check status, I need to execute method that checks status of each row, looks for check box column and does some math on other columns based on that check status.

So far every event that I tried: `CellContentClick`, CellMouseUp`,`CellValidated`,`CellValueChanged`fire AFTER I leave the cell or grabs`DataGridViewCheckBox` check status that is prior to change action.

What event allows to get the `Value` right after it changed but before I leave the cell or row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn TrueValue and FalseValue properties. Then you should handle DataGridView CellContentClick and CellValueChanged, in order to determine whether the cell is checked or not.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var checkBoxColumn = (DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)this.dataGridView1.Columns[0];
        checkBoxColumn.TrueValue = true;
        checkBoxColumn.FalseValue = false;

        this.dataGridView1.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellContentClick);
        this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = (sender as DataGridView).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

        if (cell != null)
        {
            if (cell.Value == cell.TrueValue)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cell checked.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cell unchecked.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGridView = sender as DataGridView;

        if (dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)
        {
            // Raise CellValueChanged
            dataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
    }
}
```